# Should I always use -Wall and -pedantic switches with g++ while learning C++?

Tags: g++

Being a --novice, I am wondering is it beneficial to always use these flags (with g++) while learning C++ ?

Thanks

Comment: "Should I always ..." tends to be an invitation for a personal opinion flamefest ... Those inclined to agree tend to voice their support while those favouring a different point of view tend to raise objections.

Comment: To add:
On first glance, "learn warn-free code" sounds like a great idea and good way forward.
On the other hand, pragmatism will set in as soon as code samples _not written by yourself_ come into play, whether you're trying things from a textbook or opensource code found elsewhere. That code is unlikely to be completely warn-free on a specific compiler.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you understand that code samples written by others will likely result in warnings with `-Wall`, then yes, it's a good flag to use because it gets you in the habit of writing code that is free of any potential gray areas the compiler may be able to identify.

`-pedantic`, on the other hand, is a trickier case. Here's what the GCC 4.4.4 manpage has to say about it:

> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not
>   follow ISO C and ISO C++.  For ISO C, follows the version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used.
>
> Valid ISO C and ISO C++ programs should compile properly with or without this option (though a rare few will require -ansi or a -std option specifying
>   the required version of ISO C).  However, without this option, certain GNU extensions and traditional C and C++ features are supported as well.  With
>   this option, they are rejected.
>
> -pedantic does not cause warning messages for use of the alternate keywords whose names begin and end with `__`.  Pedantic warnings are also disabled in
>   the expression that follows "`__`extension`__`".  However, only system header files should use these escape routes; application programs should avoid
>   them.
>
> Some users try to use -pedantic to check programs for strict ISO C conformance.  They soon find that it does not do quite what they want: it finds
>   some non-ISO practices, but not all---only those for which ISO C requires a diagnostic, and some others for which diagnostics have been added.
>
> A feature to report any failure to conform to ISO C might be useful in some instances, but would require considerable additional work and would be
>   quite different from -pedantic.  We don't have plans to support such a feature in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer but there's the `-Weffc++` flag which emits warnings for constructs that violate guidelines in *Effective C++* (the book by Scott Meyer).

While these guidelines are good they can also be too strict eg. the STL headers will issue warnings.

Comment: If you include with `-isystem /PATH/TO/STL` rather then `-I  /PATH/TO/STL` you should be able to avoid system headers giving warnings.